# How to display Map inside recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin

I've `Map<String<List<Person>>`, the String should act like a header, and the String values(`List<Person>`) should acts like item list.

I tested my adapter with regular list and I'm able to choose which view to represent based on position

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    if (position == 0) {
        return Type.HEADER.ordinal
    } else {
        return Type.ROW.ordinal
    }
}
```

My question is How can I map a `Map<String<List<SomeClass>>`, so the keys will return `Type.HEADER.ordinal`, and the values will return `Type.ROW.ordinal`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapters in Android should work with a list of items.
You will need to map your `Map` object to a `List`

I suggest you to use a Sealed class for the different type of row you want to show into your adapter, and have one implementation for your header and other for your person:

```
sealed class Item {
    data class HeaderItem(val title: String) : Item()
    data class PersonItem(val person: Person) : Item()
}
```

Then you need to flatmap your `Map<String, List<Person>>` object to a `List<Item>`

```
val myMap: Map<String, List<Person>> = getData()
val myItems: List<Item> = myMap.flatMap { listOf(Item.HeaderItem(it.key)) + it.value.map { Item.PersonItem(it) } }
```

And into your adapter, because it will have a `List<Item>`, when it is asking for the View Type of a position you could do something like:

```
class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    ...
    var items: List<Item> = listOf()

    fun addItem(newItems: List<Item>) {
        items = items + newItems
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int = when (items[position]) {
        is Item.HeaderItem -> Type.HEADER.ordinal
        is Item.PersonItem -> Type.ROW.ordinal
    }
}
```